# Draw wireframe overlay of model in GLSL

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl, ogre

I have a 3D model that has a GLSL script, and I want to draw a line on each border of its polygons in the fragment shader.

What should I do? Note: I am using Ogre3D, so I can't use OpenGL's functions.

So far I have this (just assigns a texture to it):

```
void main(void)
{
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1, gl_TexCoord[0].st); 
}
```

This means if I have a cube, I want to render 12 lines, on each border of the cube

Comment: possible duplicate of [outline object effect](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34652/outline-object-effect)

Comment: What about cell shading? http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Enhanced+CelShading If you're new to Ogre, be sure to go through their framework tutorial and understand the pipeline.

Comment: Or this (silhouette outlining) http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=64186 . These are not trivial for a beginner in Ogre.. so be sure you are comfortable with this engine.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough. I want to draw a border on each border of each polygon. This means if I have a cube, I want to render 12 lines, on each border of the cube

Comment: So... a wireframe overlay?

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch, you're spot on (according to the OP's edit). That shouldn't be hard to achieve with Ogre and a 2-pass material. http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=45407&start=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to do it in a shader using the linked comment above.

But if that doesn't work, you can still do it by rendering a separate batch of lines *after* drawing your shape.

If this is just a debug mode thing, there is no need to do this particularly efficiently: just walk the triangles of the mesh and draw a line along each edge of each triangle.

If this *is* going to be a runtime thing, you need to eliminate the duplicate edges that will result from adjacent triangles.

Comment: For debug it's easier still to just set things in wireframe mode.  Set `polygon_mode` to `wireframe` in the `pass` section of a .material file, in Ogre3D, or in other parts of the renderer if you don't want to use a custom pass for the effect.  D3D and GL have their own lower level ways to set polygon display modes between wireframe or solid/fill.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ogre3D, then why don't you do add another pass to the material technique that is assigned to the model, as in (suppose "ball" is an Ogre::Entity):

```
Ogre::MaterialPtr ptr = ball->getSubEntity(0)->getMaterial();
Ogre::Pass * pass = ptr->getTechnique(0)->createPass();
pass->setDiffuse(1,0,0,0); 
pass->setAmbient(1,0,0);  
pass->setPolygonModeOverrideable(true);
pass->setPolygonMode(Ogre::PM_WIREFRAME);
```

This will add a red wireframe that gets drawn over the existing material.  And if you just want a wireframe, not a wireframe on top of the current material, just substitute "getPass(0)" for "createPass()"

Or, if you would rather do it in the .material file:

```
material general/wireframe
{
  technique
  {
    // first pass
    pass
    {
      polygon_mode wireframe
      ...
```

See:

http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/manual/manual_16.html#polygon_005fmode
http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/manual/manual_14.html#Material-Scripts