# How would one outline an alpha transparency layer in javscript and/or php?

Tags: javascript, webgl, php, three.js, outline

I simply want an outline/edge detection of the character/item/object that is selected or doing something.

I'm seeing lots of versions of this question for different languages, but I would appreciate an approach that can be implemented in a web context. I don't know if this is better dealt with in the server or can be done on the client side. I have no idea of how to access the alpha transparency layer in any language. Please advise. Sorry for the lack of specificity, just getting a handle on what I want. This would be in a 2d context.

This picture [outline object effect](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34652/outline-object-effect) shows what i'm going for. Not sure if answers in that question apply to my problem.

Comment: It seems to me that [that question you linked](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34652/outline-object-effect) is the same as this one, but clearer. Are you using raw WebGL from JavaScript or coding through something like *three.js*? What does PHP have to do with this?

Comment: The difference between my question and the one I link to is that I would like to implement that effect in javascript. I'm not familiar with what they are using in the other question.

Comment: You could use drop-shadows, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186688/drop-shadow-for-png-image-in-css

Comment: @bummzack there is a lot to look at here. this effect can only be applied to .png .svg etc?

Answer (score 1):

Neither JS nor PHP are very suitable for what you're trying to do. You can define transparency in PHP (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php), but I'm not sure if you can actually read it out. Also understand that PHP is a server side language, so for any real-time interaction of on-screen elements it's not very suitable.

You bets bet is probably looking at WebGL HTML5 & "canvas" tag

Pixel manipulation: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#pixel-manipulation

MDN ImageData reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/ImageData

Comment: isn't WebGL and canvas manipulated through js?

Comment: Wait, why isn't JS suitable for programming a web-based game? I'm not aware of any alternatives.

Comment: it's suitable for web based games, but not for reading out alpha channel of images.

Comment: what is the language that is most like the ones i'm using that could solve this problem? That other question seems to be more C#-oriented. DO i have to go down that road?

Comment: Personally, I'd do this by rendering the outline image offline in Photoshop and then save it as a frame in a sprite. Then you can use it any JS framework. Everything else seems a bit overkill in my opinion.

Comment: the outline of the shape could be constantly moving.

Comment: if the shape is changing based on calculations you can apply the same base calculations (possibly modified) to animate the outline shape. If it's based on a an animated sprite you can create a 2nd sprite.